# How to use e.preventDefault inside onChange for select tag

Tags: javascript, html, select, dom-events, preventdefault

Is there a way we can stop changing the select tag value by using `preventDefault`. 
I can prevent input from changing the value by using `event.preventDefault`
But not able to prevent the select tag from changing the value.

Here's a sample code:

```js
document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('select', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});

document.getElementById('my-input').addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="my-input">
```

Comment: The change event happens after the change has already happened.  You would need logic to signify the previous value and to revert it in the case that it should not happen.  Or optionally, alter the select so the users cannot select invalid values in the first place.

Comment: Just disable the select like `<select id="my-select" disabled>`

Answer (score 0):

Select event listener should be 'change' instead of .addEventListener('select' ...

However, the change event in a select HTML element is not cancellable in order to call preventDefault(). If you log the event object you will see that it's cancelable property is set to false. Perhaps you can set the select element to disabled.

Comment: Well disabling select can't act as a solution for me as I've to kinda open a confirm modal and only change the select tag value if the user confirms from the modal.